# Is there a way in .bash_profile, to create two aliases that do the same thing?

Tags: bash, macos, alias

I have some simple aliases in my `.bash_profile` (OS X El Capitan, 10.11.6). Sometimes, I want multiple aliases that do the same thing. I have, for example, a folder that is my starting point for programming projects. Currently, I have an alias for code and one for programming that do the same thing:

```
alias code='cd /path/to/Programming/; clear; pwd; ls'
alias programming='cd /path/to/Programming/; clear; pwd; ls'
```

This saves me having to remember how I aliased this directory. Is there a way to set multiple aliases without having to repeat the command? In short, is there something like this?

```
alias code,programming='cd /path/to/Programming/; clear; pwd; ls'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> In short, is there something like this?
>
> `alias code,programming='cd /path/to/Programming/; clear; pwd; ls'`

Yes, brace expansion:

```
alias {code,programming}='cd /path/to/Programming/; clear; pwd; ls'
```

Comment: Wow! That really works. I wonder why since `alias a b='cmd --foo'` doesn't work.

Comment: `{a,b}=foo` becomes `a=foo b=foo`

Comment: This worked for me. It's going to greatly simplify things. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can only provide one name per body, but you can define one name to be an alias to the other in the same command. For example,

```
alias code='cd /path/to/Programming/; clear; pwd; ls' programming=code
```

In practice, I recommend defining a function instead of an alias for the "real" one.

```
code () {
  cd /path/to/Programming
  clear
  pwd
  ls
}

alias programming=code
```

---

On an unrelated tangent, `zsh` does allow defining multiple names for a single function:

```
code programming () {
  cd /path/to/Programming
  clear
  pwd
  ls
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
alias foo='ls'   # Arbitrary command. I've used ls for example
alias bar='foo'  # Use alias from previous definition
```

This can be also one line:

```
alias foo='ls' bar='foo'
```

For more info type `help alias` in your shell.

---

Btw, I would put these aliases into `.bashrc` rather than `.bash_profile`: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
alias code='cd /path/to/Programming/; clear; pwd; ls'
alias programming='code'
```

or even multiple assignments in a single `alias` statement, see [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53069604/3266847).

When expanding an alias, the first word is checked for being an alias again, so you can "chain" them, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases):

> The first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases, but a word that is identical to an alias being expanded is not expanded a second time.

This allows for aliases like

```
alias ls='ls -F'
```

without infinite recursion.